# how do i remove some errors from moving a file in python

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems

#this code works but it throws errors.
#can someone review this to find some problems with it.

```
    import os
import shutil
import time

path = "./folder1/"
moveto = "./folder2/"
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()


def fileMovement():
    for f in files:
        src = path + f
        dst = moveto + f
        shutil.move(src, dst)


while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    fileMovement()
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, do you want us to test your code and find errors? That is not what this site is for. If you have specific exceptions happening then people can direct you and help you solve them.

Comment: Also, it is generally safer to use ``os.path.join`` to create file paths.

Comment: i mean this code works but, it gives me spisific errors when I added 'while True:

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.